# How can I stress test my Postfix system without actually sending existing addesses mails?

Tags: postfix

I'd like to stress my Postfix servers, and I need to make a huge amount of sendings, but of course, I don't want to send spam to any real address, and I don't my IP's to be blacklisted.

Is there any way of configuring postfix this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here https://web.archive.org/web/20140912030425/http://postfixmail.com/blog/index.php/postfix-stress-test/

> One of the questions that you will want to solve is how much mail
> traffic can your hardware handle.  This is often why people overbuild
> hardware is that they just are not sure and no one wants to build a
> mail server and then rebuild in 3 months.  Fortunately, Postfix comes
> with a couple programs that you can stress your server with and get a
> general idea of what you need.
>
> Hardware Considerations - When you are building a mail server,
> especially if you are building a mail server that will host multiple
> domains, it is very difficult to determine the necessary hardware as
> growth is unknown in two areas.  First, growth in terms of new domains
> or new accounts on the mail server is tough because business can
> change and staff may change dramatically in a 6 month period. When you
> build the mail server you want to build something that will
> potentially provide 3 years of service, maybe 5.  So you must
> compensate for the amount of growth for your business.  Second, growth
> is difficult to estimate based on the amount of Spam your server must
> be capable of managing.  This is a very frustrating aspect of mail
> servers in that potentially, Spam could triple in 3 months and it
> would have very little to do with how you are managing your mail
> server, so you must also prepare for these kinds of issues.  Spam is
> especially hard on resources as you will be running a programs like
> Spamassassin and an anti-virus program like ClamAv on each of these
> emails that hits your system.
>
> Stress Test - The program smtp-source will use port 25  to simulate mail
> coming to your mail server to process.  In this simulation you can
> perform messages by themselves or in parallel.  There are several
> settings that you can modify to help determine the stress level that
> your server will best perform at. In order to run the test you may
> have to comment out a few lines in your smtpd restrictions.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_recipient
#   reject_non_fqdn_sender
#   reject_unknown_sender_domain reject_unknown_recipient_domain permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination reject_non_fqdn_hostname reject_invalid_hostname
#   check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_checks check_sender_mx_access cidr:/etc/postfix/bogus_mx reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org reject_unverified_sender permit
```

> Parallel sessions – This will indicate the number of concurrent
> sessions or maxprocesses that your server will be running.
>
> Message size – You can test various message sizes to simulate the mail
> that you typically will receive on your server.
>
> Total messages – You can determine the total messages  that you will
> test on receiving.
>
> Display counter -This will just show a counter as the messages are
> received while the command is running.

```
# time /usr/sbin/smtp-source -s 20 -l 5120 -m 100 -c -f test@example.com -t mike@example.com localhost:25  100

real    0m2.664s user    0m0.020s sys    0m0.100s
```

> This example shows 20 parallel sessions (-s 20), 5KB sized messages
> (-l 5120), 100 messages ent (-m 100), counter display (-c), envelope
> sender and receiver (-f test@example.com -t  mike@example.com) and
> connection on port 25 of the localhost (localhost:25). The “100”
> indicates the total messages sent.  The real time (0m2.664s ) is the
> time the injection took,. Here is an additional test on the same
> server that indicates an increase to 40 sessions, 10 KB mail size and
> 500 messages.  This gives you a way to evaluate the additional load on
> the server in terms of a comparison time.

```
# time /usr/sbin/smtp-source -s 40 -l 10120 -m 500 -c -f test@example.com -t    mike@example.com localhost:25  500

real    0m29.795s user    0m0.200s sys    0m0.530s
```

Comment: Answers with only a link to content are strongly discouraged. What happens when that link goes dead? Your answer becomes worthless. Please provide content **here** and link to the source for more detail.

Comment: Hi guys, I ran the command and here is the output. Is this "fatal: usage" stuff a bug or normal output?
`time /usr/sbin/smtp-source -s 20 -l 5120 -m 100 -c -f test@example.com -t mike@example.com localhost:25  100
/usr/sbin/smtp-source: fatal: usage: /usr/sbin/smtp-source -cdLNov -s sess -l msglen -m msgs -C count -M myhostname -f from -t to -r rcptcount -R delay -w delay host[:port]

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
`

Answer (score -1):

This command is beautiful for #StressTest #Performance #CapacityPlanning

```
# time /usr/sbin/smtp-source -s 20 -l 5120 -m 100 -c -f test@example.com -t mike@example.com localhost:25  100

real    0m2.664s user    0m0.020s sys    0m0.100s
```

In my case: (Debian Weezy) the "100" at the final not corresponding with the syntax.

```
# time /usr/sbin/smtp-source -s 20 -l 5120 -m 100 -c -f test@example.com -t mike@example.com localhost:25

real    0m2.664s user    0m0.020s sys    0m0.100s
```